# dynamic catalog product search amounts

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm looking for a way to dynamically vary the limit of products per page in my catalog.
For example, I have 2 categories, catA has 17 products, catB has 15 products.

I want catA to paginate every 14 items.
I want catB to paginate every 15 items.

The rule being any category with 16+ items will paginating at 14, but anything < 16 items will display all items (which means 15 items doesn't create a 2nd page).

Can anyone direct me where I could insert logic to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a new category attribute "page_at"
2. Manipulate the product collection via observer "product_collection_load_before" or a rewrite of the List-Block (List.php).
3. Inside your collection do the manipulation (one of the two ways from 2.) via

> $collection->setPageSize($category->getPageAt())